# No consigo que el cursor me lea lo que devuelve la sentencia SQL- Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite

Estoy creando una app de tipo calendario y cuando ejecuto al app y le doy a la opcíon de ver eventos me da error en el cursor: El error es el siguiente "***Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accesing data from it.***"

Os pongo los códigos del proyecto a continuación:
En este solo llama a las siguientes actividades

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.CalendarView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  
CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener{


private CalendarView calendarview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    calendarview= findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    calendarview.setOnDateChangeListener(this);
}
// este método saltara cuando se cambie las fechas en el calendario
@Override
public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    CharSequence [] items = new CharSequence[3]; //contenerá las opciones 
que podrá escoger el usuario
    items[0]= "Agregar eventos";
    items[1]="Ver eventos";
    items[2]="Cancelar";

    final int dia,mes,anio;
    dia=i2;
    mes=i1+1;// esto es por que el més empieza en cero y de esta manera se evita eso
    anio=i;


    //Le ponemos título a la alerta y le ponemos las opciones más un 
escuchador de cuando presione dichas opciones
    builder.setTitle("Seleccione una opción")
            .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                    //comparamos la opción seleccionada
                    if (i==0){
                        //actividad agregar eventos
                        Intent intent=new Intent( getApplicationContext(), 
AddActivity.class);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"dia "+dia+" ,Mes 
"+mes+", AÑO "+anio, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        intent.putExtra("dia",dia);
                        intent.putExtra("mes",mes);
                        intent.putExtra("anio",anio);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }else if (i==1){
                        //ver actividad eventos
                        Intent intent=new Intent( getApplicationContext(), ViewEventsActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("dia",dia);
                        intent.putExtra("mes",mes);
                        intent.putExtra("anio",anio);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        //selecciona cancelar y salimos del método
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });

    AlertDialog dialog=builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
}
```

Este es el añade eventos:

```
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText nombreEvento;
private EditText ubicacion;
private EditText fechaDesde;
private EditText horaDesde;
private EditText fechaHasta;
private EditText horaHasta;
private EditText descripcion;
private Button guardar, cancelar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
    nombreEvento= findViewById(R.id.edtNombreEvento);
    ubicacion=findViewById(R.id.edtUbicacion);
    fechaDesde=findViewById(R.id.edtFechaDesde);
    fechaHasta=findViewById(R.id.edtFechaHasta);
    horaDesde=findViewById(R.id.edtHoraInicio);
    horaHasta=findViewById(R.id.edtHoraHasta);
    descripcion=findViewById(R.id.edtDescripcion);

    Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
    int dia,mes,anio;
    dia=bundle.getInt("dia");
    mes=bundle.getInt("mes");
    anio=bundle.getInt("anio");

    Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"dia "+dia+" ,Mes "+mes+", AÑO "+anio, 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    fechaDesde.setText(dia+"-"+mes+"-"+ anio);
    fechaHasta.setText(dia+"-"+mes+"-"+ anio);

    guardar=findViewById(R.id.btnGuardar);
    cancelar= findViewById(R.id.btnCancelar);

    guardar.setOnClickListener(this);
    cancelar.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    //comparamos la opción presionada
    if(view.getId()==guardar.getId()){
        //guardar los datos de las caja de texto
        BDSQLite bd = new BDSQLite(getApplication(), "Agenda",null,1);
        SQLiteDatabase db= bd.getWritableDatabase(); //Le asignamos los 
datos en modo String para guardarlos

        String sql= "insert into eventos "+
                "   


(nombreEvento,ubicacion,fechadesde,horadesde,fechahasta,horahasta,descripcion) 
        values('"
                    +nombreEvento.getText()+
                    "','"+ubicacion.getText()
                    + "','" + fechaDesde.getText()+
                    " ','"+ horaDesde.getText()
                    +"','"+ fechaHasta.getText()
                    +"','"+ horaHasta.getText()
                    +"','"+ descripcion.getText()+"')";

        try{
            db.execSQL(sql);
            nombreEvento.setText("");
            ubicacion.setText("");
            fechaDesde.setText("");
            horaDesde.setText("");
            fechaHasta.setText("");
            horaHasta.setText("");
            descripcion.setText("");
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Error"+e.getMessage(), 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }else{
        this.finish();
        return;
    }
}
}
```

Esta actividad muestra los eventos **AQUÍ ME DA ERROR**:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class ViewEventsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener{

    //Declaramos un array el cual uaremos para leer los datos de la base de datos
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String >arrayAdapter;


    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_events);

        listView=findViewById(R.id.ltvListaEventos);
        //nos sirve para cuando se mantiene presionado un item en la lista y para borrar elementos
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);


        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        int dia,mes,anio;
        dia= bundle.getInt("dia");
        mes= bundle.getInt("mes");
        anio= bundle.getInt("anio");

        //metemos los valores en un String para poder validar los datos en la BBDD
        String cadena= anio+ " - " +mes+ " - " +dia;

        //conectamos a nuestra BBDD en modo lectura
        BDSQLite bd= new BDSQLite(getApplicationContext(),"Agenda",null,1);
        db = bd.getReadableDatabase();//modo lectura
        String sql=" select count(*) from eventos";
        //delcaramos una variable de tipod Cursor que nos servira para guardar los registros que nos devuelva la consulta
        Cursor c;
        //declaramos variables temporales para almacenar los datos temporalmente
        String nombre, fechadesde,fechahasta,descripcion,ubicacion;
        try{
            //los registros que nos devuelva los guardamos  en c
            c= db.rawQuery(sql,null);//****NO ME LEE NADA****
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),String.valueOf(c.getCount()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Log.i("Count",String.valueOf(c.getCount()));

            //instanciamos el arrayAdapter
            arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            //comparamos que haya datos para leer
            if(c!=null){
                c.moveToFirst();

                do{
                    String ident= c.getString(0);
                    nombre=c.getString(1);
                    ubicacion=c.getString(2);
                    fechadesde=c.getString(3);
                    fechahasta=c.getString(5);
                    descripcion=c.getString(7);

                    arrayAdapter.add("id"+ident+","+nombre+", "+ubicacion+", "+fechadesde+", "+fechahasta+", "+descripcion);
                }while (c.moveToNext());
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            }else{
            //si no hay datos en el cursor no mostramos la interfaz
            this.finish();
        }

        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Error eeeeeeeeee    "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //si ocurre algun error cierra la interfaz
            this.finish();
        }

    }

    private void eliminar(String dato){
        String[]datos=dato.split(", ");

        String sql="Delete from eventos where nombreEvento='"+datos[0]+"' and ubicacion='"+datos[1]+"' and fechadesde='"+datos[2]+"' and fechahasta='"+datos[3]+"' and descripcion='"+datos[4]+"'";
        try {
            arrayAdapter.remove(dato);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            db.execSQL(sql);
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Evento eliminado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Error"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
//agregamos un dialogo para que el usuario pueda eliminar el evento
        AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        CharSequence[] items = new CharSequence[1];
        items[0]="Eliminar eventos";
        items[1]="Cancelar";
        builder.setTitle("Eliminar evento")
                .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                        if (i == 0) {
                            //eliminar evento
                            //le pasamos el dato que selecciona el usuario
                            eliminar(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString());
                        }
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog dialog =builder.create();
        dialog.show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Por último os dejo la base de datos:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class BDSQLite extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private String sql = "create table eventos(" +
            "idEvento integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "nombreEvento varchar(40)," +
            "ubicacion varchar(60)," +
            "fechadesde date," +
            "horadesde time," +
            "fechahasta date," +
            "horahasta time," +
            "descripcion varchar(60))";

    public BDSQLite(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mensaje de error indica que no puede leer el elemento en el cursor

> Couldn't read row 0, col 1 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is
>   initialized correctly before accesing data from it.

Te sugiero revisar estos puntos que pueden provocar el problema que presentas:

- Es importante que revises la consulta ya que probablemente no obtiene resultados o tu tabla esta vacía.

En este caso estas usando la funcion count() lo cual es una causa del problema:

```
String sql=" select count(*) from eventos";
```

cambia a:

```
String sql=" select * from eventos";
```

- Recuerda que si realizaste pruebas para construir la base de datos, puede existir la posibilidad de tener una estructura incorrecta, para esto elimina la aplicación y cargala nuevamente a tu dispositivo.
- Recuerda siempre cerrar los cursores al terminar de obtener los datos del mismo, para esto usa el método `.close()`.

Te sugiero cambiar la lectura de los datos de tu cursor de:

```
 if(c!=null){
                c.moveToFirst();

                do{
                    String ident= c.getString(0);
                    nombre=c.getString(1);
                    ubicacion=c.getString(2);
                    fechadesde=c.getString(3);
                    fechahasta=c.getString(5);
                    descripcion=c.getString(7);

                    arrayAdapter.add("id"+ident+","+nombre+", "+ubicacion+", "+fechadesde+", "+fechahasta+", "+descripcion);
                }while (c.moveToNext());
                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

            }else{
            //si no hay datos en el cursor no mostramos la interfaz
            this.finish();
        }
```

a esta forma, donde se cierra el cursor:

```
 if(c!=null){
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                String ident= c.getString(0);
                nombre=c.getString(1);
                ubicacion=c.getString(2);
                fechadesde=c.getString(3);
                fechahasta=c.getString(5);
                descripcion=c.getString(7);

                arrayAdapter.add("id"+ident+","+nombre+", "+ubicacion+", "+fechadesde+", "+fechahasta+", "+descripcion);
            }
            //Cierra cursor.
            c.close();
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        }else{
        //si no hay datos en el cursor no mostramos la interfaz
        this.finish();
    }
```